# Using ParseRecyclerQueryAdapter

Tags: java, android, parse-platform, android-recyclerview

Please I would like someone to help point me in the right direction with using the ParseRecyclerQueryAdapter. I'm trying to retrieve articles with my current adapter class that implements the standard RecyclerView. my implementation of pagination is not working properly soIi would like a demonstration from anyone that has used the ParseRecyclerQueryAdapter to achieve the following. By translating it from me so I get the implementation.

```
public class ArticleRVAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {

List<Article> articleData = Collections.emptyList();
private LayoutInflater inflater;
private Context context;

public ArticleRVAdapter(Context context, List<Article> data){
    inflater=LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.articleData= data;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public ArticleViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.article_item, parent, false);
    ArticleViewHolder viewHolder = new ArticleViewHolder(view);
    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return articleData.size();
}

public class ArticleViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
        implements View.OnClickListener {

    CardView cardView;
    TextView title;
    TextView body;
    Date dateCreated;
    TextView author;
    ImageView headImage;
    String objectId;

    public ArticleViewHolder(final View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        itemView.setClickable(true);
        itemView.setLongClickable(true);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);


        cardView = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_article);
        title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_title);
        body = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_article_body);
        //dateCreated = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_article_body);
        author = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_author);
        headImage = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView_thumb);


    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), ArticleInformationActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("article_id", articleData.get(getLayoutPosition()).getObjectId());
        intent.putExtra("article_title", articleData.get(getLayoutPosition()).getArticleTitle());
        intent.putExtra("article_body", articleData.get(getLayoutPosition()).getArticleBody());
        intent.putExtra("article_author", articleData.get(getLayoutPosition()).getArticleAuthor());
        intent.putExtra("article_date", articleData.get(getLayoutPosition()).getDateCreated());
        v.getContext().startActivity(intent);

    }
}
```

Comment: The current implementation works, but I want to use ParseRecyclerQueryAdapter

Comment: Have you seen this? https://gist.github.com/ameron32/34329dbd5856bf5ea7c3

Comment: I have and that's the Class I'm asking to be translated from this. I did try implementing but never really got it working

Comment: You just need to extend parserecycleadapter

Comment: K, thanks figured it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of testing, I got the solution in my project:

**Fragment (or Activity)**:

```
private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
private MyQueryAdapter myQueryAdapter;
private SwipeRefreshLayout swipeRefreshLayout;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_fragment, container, false);
        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.rv);
        myQueryAdapter = new MyQueryAdapter(true);

        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(myQueryAdapter);

        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));

        myQueryAdapter.addOnQueryLoadListener(new ParseRecyclerQueryAdapter.OnQueryLoadListener<MY_MODEL>() {
            @Override
            public void onLoaded(List<MY_MODEL> objects, Exception e) {
                if (swipeRefreshLayout.isRefreshing()) {
                    swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onLoading() {
                if (!swipeRefreshLayout.isRefreshing()) {
                    swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);
                }

            }
        });



        swipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.swipe_container);
        swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
                myQueryAdapter.loadObjects();
            }
        });


        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        myQueryAdapter.loadObjects();
    }
```

**Adapter**

```
public class MyQueryAdapter extends ParseRecyclerQueryAdapter<MY_MODEL, MyQueryAdapter.MyViewHolder>{


    public MyQueryAdapter(boolean hasStableIds) {
        super(MY_MODEL.class, hasStableIds);
    }

public MarcacionesAdapter(ParseQueryAdapter.QueryFactory<Marcaciones> factory, boolean hasStableIds) {
        super(factory, hasStableIds);
    }



    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.cardview, parent, false);
        MyViewHolder myViewHolder = new MyViewHolder(v);
        return myViewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

        MY_MODEL model = getItem(position);
        holder.name.setText(model.getName());
        holder.year.setText(model.getYear());

    }

    public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        CardView cv;
        TextView name;
        TextView year;

        MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            cv = (CardView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_view);
            name = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.name);
            year = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.year);
        }
    }

}
```

If you want to configure a custom query, you can do it in this way:

```
       factory =
                new ParseQueryAdapter.QueryFactory<MY_MODEL>() {
                    public ParseQuery< MY_MODEL > create() {

                        ParseQuery<MY_MODEL> query = MY_MODEL.getQuery();
                        query.include("user");

                        //Filter by date
                        query.whereGreaterThan("createdAt", midnight);
                        query.whereLessThan("createdAt", now);

                        query.orderByDescending("createdAt");


                        return query;
                    }
                };

        adapter = new MyQueryAdapter(factory, true);
```

Comment: In which activity should I create custom Query?

Comment: where its  giving me error cannot assign boolean to ParseObject class because of hasStableIds